# Calculating amino acid mol/mol ratios

Tags: biochemistry, mole, amino-acids

I am trying to understand how the authors calculated the TRP/LNAA (mol/mol) ratios in Table 1 in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00213-008-1254-0#Tab1).

For example, when I calculate the TRP/LNAA (mol/mol) ratio for HPROT, I get 0.14 instead of 1.1. What am doing wrong?

I'm using the following values for the molecular weights (g/mol):

- Isoleucine 131.2
- Leucine 131.2
- Phenylalanine 165.2
- Tyrosine 181.2
- Valine 117.1
- Tryptophan 204.2

And here are the tables from the paper:

> **Table 1:** Composition of the standard protein (PLC), alpha-lactalbumin whey protein (ALAC), protein hydrolase (HPROT), pure tryptophan (TRP), and synthetic dipeptide (SYN) condition
>
> \begin{array}{llll}
> \hline
> \text{Source} & \text{Product}~(\mathrm{g}) & \text{TRP}~(\mathrm{g}) & \text{TRP/LNAA}~(\mathrm{mol}/\mathrm{mol}) \\
> \hline
> \text{PLC}   & 20~\mathrm{g}/312~\mathrm{mL}  & 0.4 & 0.04   \\
> \text{ALAC}  & 15~\mathrm{g}/312~\mathrm{mL}  & 0.8 & 0.1    \\
> \text{HPROT} & 312~\mathrm{mL}       & 0.8 & 1.1    \\
> \text{TRP}   & 0.8~\mathrm{g}/312~\mathrm{mL} & 0.8 & \infty \\
> \text{SYN}   & 1.2~\mathrm{g}/312~\mathrm{mL} & 0.8 & \infty \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
>
> **Table 2:** Amino acid profile
>
> \begin{array}{llll}
> \hline
> \text{Amino acid profile}~(\mathrm{g}) & \text{HPROT} & \text{PLC} & \text{ALAC} \\
> \hline
> \text{Isoleucine}    & 1.004 & 1.800 & 2.012 \\
> \text{Leucine}       & 0.745 & 2.733 & 3.306 \\
> \text{Phenylalanine} & 0.480 & 1.467 & 1.309 \\
> \text{Tyrosine}      & 1.216 & 1.867 & 1.451 \\
> \text{Valine}        & 0.554 & 2.133 & 1.322 \\
> \text{Tryptophan}    & 0.8   & 0.4   & 0.8   \\
> \hline
> \text{Total}         & 3.999 & 10    & 9.4   \\
> \hline
> \end{array}

Acronyms:

- LNAA: large neutral amino acids
- HPROT: hydrolyzed protein

Comment: How did you calculate moles of LNAA since there are 6 of them? I'd also point out what I consider to be a flaw in the paper in general, and that is that serotonin synthesis is not directly dependent on TRP, but rather on 5-hydroxtryptophan since tryptophan hydroxylase is the rate limiting enzyme in 5-HT synthesis. Feeding tyrptophan to humans does little to raise brain 5-HT.  Giving human 5HTP however does increase brain 5-HT.

Comment: @DrJ I calculated the moles for each individual amino acid and then summed the resulting values.

Comment: By the way, the paper does not make claims regarding serotonin synthesis. Rather, they investigate links between dietary intake of TRP/LNAA, serum levels of TRP/LNAA, and mood scores

Comment: But the “mood” is ultimately supposed to be related to brain serotonin levels, and this has been fairly well documented (refer to many articles by M.A. Aprison, et.al.). But that’s off topic from your question. I didnt see where they provided the mass of each LNAA in the diet. If you direct me to those data, I can check your calculations.

Comment: Citation was meant to be M.H. Aprison. Sorry.

Comment: The masses for the amino acids are here (Table 2): https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00213-008-1254-0#Tab2 It's entirely possible that I am making an elementary error (!)

Comment: Yes, the calculated ratio is 0.14. Hard to imagine how it could be > 1.0 considering the combination of 6 LNAA compared to the lonely tryptophan.  Unless there is something unique about the HPROT being used in this study, i.e. what is the TRP content of the hydrolysate? I didn't read the entire manuscript, so I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: @DrJ Thanks for checking the calculation, much appreciated. I think there's something funny going on in this paper but I'm not sure what yet - I'll continue thinking about it. Though at this point,  I think Table 1 is just plain wrong.